# Do I need a copy of a framework I'm using in the web app directory?

Tags: web-applications

If I'm building a web app and want to use a framework like bootstrap or express. Do I need a copy of that framework in the same directory or can I just install them in one set location with the libraries I use for other languages

Comment: Yes, you can copy them in you web app directory and use given correct path

Answer (score 0):

The `href` you provide is just a URL, so you can refer to any local or remote location. You could also use a content delivery network (CDN), here is an example for Bootstrap:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >`